# Laravel 5.2 custom validation error message with parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I am pretty sure I am missing just something small, but damn-hell can't figure it out.. please help me guys :)

I've extended **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        //
        Validator::extend('ageLimit', 'App\Http\CustomValidator@validateAgeLimit');
    }
```

I've created new **CustomValidator.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;
use DateTime;

class CustomValidator {

    public function validateAgeLimit($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $today = new DateTime(date('m/d/Y'));
        $bday  = new DateTime($value);

        $diff = $bday->diff($today);
        $first_param = $parameters[0];

        if( $diff->y >= $first_param ){              
            return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }

    }

}
```

I've added new line to **validation.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/
'age_limit' => ':attribute -> Age must be at least :ageLimit years old.',

'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],
```

Here comes my rule:

```
'birth_date' => 'required|date|ageLimit:15',
```

All of this works ok ... excluded the parameter :ageLimit in validation.php file ..

How can I get there the parameter 15 I am passing in rule ???

Because I am getting this message:

```
Birth day -> Age must be at least :ageLimit years old.
```

And certainly, I would like to get this:

```
Birth day -> Age must be at least 15 years old.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below your `Validator::extend(...)` you could add:

```
Validator::replacer('ageLimit', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
    $ageLimit = $parameters[0];

    return str_replace(':ageLimit', $ageLimit, $message);
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Hope this helps!